# Is there an efficient way to round string that has double value inside and get answer as double?

Tags: java, formatting, format, string-formatting, number-formatting

So my question is a bit confusing but still. I get an array of 8 strings from outside source that all contain doubles values inside. Those values are usually in 4 decimal places:

> 12345.5678

What I would like to do is to convert it to 3 decimal places as well as round it up and have the result on the output:

> 12345.568

Here is the code example:

```
private double[] parseDouble(String[] values) { 
    double[] output = new double[values.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { 
        output[i] = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.3f", 
        Double.parseDouble(values[i]));
    } 
    return output; 
}
```

So my questions are:

1.**Is there any better way than that?** Because parsing to double 2 times is pretty redundant in my opinion.

2.**Will it anyhow affect the performance if a number of values in the string array is around 100-1000?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just round the `double` after parsing? Looking at what you seem to be doing here, it looks like `BigDecimal` would be more appropriate if you want this sort of base 10 digit-exact precision. `double` won't ever quite get that for you.

Comment: you need to parse only once(String to Double) the rest is just a format

Comment: what do you mean with ***double[] output = double(values.length);***???

Comment: that's an honest mistake I made it should be double[] output = new double[values.length];

Answer (score 0):

For the sanity of the answer I can suggest this but you dont need to declare the array result

```
private double[] parseDouble(String[] values) {
    double[] result = Arrays.stream(values).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();
    return result;
}
```

now that will only parse the strings into doubles...

for how they look like you need a formatter:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
double[] x = { 12345.5678, Math.PI, 123.123451, Math.E };
Arrays.stream(x).forEach(n -> System.out.println(df.format(n)));
```

I suggest to combine those 2 approaches and remember a double is a double no matter how many decimal places is getting printed.

Comment: That's the thing! I don't need to print it out, there are calculations I need to do with values of the array, it is why the method itself should return the array of doubles, rounded to 3 decimal places. Also, it seems that any kind of formater takes arguments as double and returns results in the string format, that's why I have to parse it to double again. I couldn't find a way to round double to 3 decimal points from 4 (I might have looked poorly) and get double as a return value.

Comment: Why do you need to round it before doing calculations? If you need an exact decimal value, you shouldn't be using `double` in the first place.

Comment: The values themselves won't be greater than 99999.999 or less than 0.000, and I need to store them in SQLite database for Android as well as retrieve later, the double format seems to be the best way since you can only save it as an int, double, or string in the database. So I tend to believe double conversion to `double` is the only way here

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you need to round it. `Double.parseDouble` gives you a double, you can store that as a double, you don't need to do anything else to it. Every double value is stored as a 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point number (Java and SQLite both follow this standard).

Comment: Sorry for late response. It has to be rounded because it is the way data should be represented for this task.